# Default prompt values for dynamic prompts based on BEx query

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

have a report build on top of a BEx query. The report parameters, which are actually variables in the query are dynamic and populated by LOVs created in Business View Manager. The issue I face is that I cannot set the default values to the parameters when I try to publish the report via Publishing Manager.

I published it without assigning defaults from Publishing Wizard. Set the default values from CMC and the values showed up. However when I view the instance from Infoview, the default values are not populated. been stuck all day on this one

Answer (score 1):

Try to Save the report to BW role first and then Publish into BO repository using BW Publisher.